# Cocos2d error - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, compiler-errors

I keep getting this error:
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)...
when I'm compiling my game.  I'm am using Cocos2d.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Check the build log in Xcode (View -> Navigator -> Log Navigator). There's got to be more errors/warnings than "exit code 1" which just says the compiler/linker process was aborted due to an error. For example:

[image]

You can select all (Cmd+A) and copy (Cmd+C) the entire log as text if you need to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any change following this guide?

http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/

If so, I had the same error because I had forgotten to remove the libs folder

> Step 6. Delete the libs group in Xcode. Make sure to select Remove References in the confirmation dialog because you’ll still be needing the files later on, so don’t trash them.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the xcworkspace to build instead of the xcproject.
This works for me.